# How to implement a function that check a condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I can't use boolean in a sql query.
Therefore I can't create a function that return true or false and use it to test a condition.
I must create a function that return something (1 for instance) and test it. Like that:

```
   WITH
    FUNCTION f (input INTEGER)
        RETURN INTEGER
    IS
    BEGIN
        RETURN CASE WHEN input = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
    END;

    A AS (SELECT 1 a FROM DUAL)
SELECT *
  FROM a
 WHERE f(a.a) = 1
```

instead of that:

```
WITH
    FUNCTION f (input INTEGER)
        RETURN boolean
    IS
    BEGIN
        RETURN  input = 1 ;
    END;

    A AS (SELECT 1 a FROM DUAL)
SELECT *
  FROM a
 WHERE f(a.a)
```

Unless there is another way?

[code](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=e7cb53467dfda459a689a16fbca98bbd)

I've tried to use a macro but to no avail

```
WITH
 FUNCTION ft 
        RETURN VARCHAR2 SQL_MACRO
    IS
    BEGIN
        RETURN q'{
      SELECT 1 
   FROM dual
  }';
    END;
    
 FUNCTION fc 
        RETURN VARCHAR2 SQL_MACRO
    IS
    BEGIN
        RETURN q'{
      1=1
  }';
    END;
SELECT *
  FROM ft()
 WHERE fc()
```

> ORA-00920: invalid relational operator

[code](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=f4628eb3cf3d2d8c2da6f7e6fe84f06b)

Comment: [About SQL Conditions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/About-SQL-Conditions.html#GUID-E9EC8434-CD48-4C01-B01B-85E5359D8DD7) lists all the possible conditions. There's no branch for custom condition and there's no `CREATE CONDITION` statement (Data Cartridge filter conditions are also implemented as a function that returns some SQL datatype or 0/1 for boolean logic). The only "function" I know that may appear in place of a condition is `LNNVL` (it is even listed in Functions section), but it works internally

Comment: @astentx also `REGEXP_LIKE` (but, again, it is a built-in function)

Comment: @MT0 This was my first thought but it is listed in the Pattern-matching Conditions alongside `LIKE` and is (correctly) not included in the Functions section. `LNNVL` may be used in place of expression, but I cannot find a useful application, it always returns `null`: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c506e072fef0d00a7f88a8d7597b6098)

Comment: @astentx You use it in the `WHERE` clause and not the `SELECT` clause [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e0e1d8aa62e4534bde61ca53b89820bf)

Comment: @MT0 Yes, this is what it is designed for. But compared to the `REGEXP_LIKE` it may also be used as an expression, not only as a condition, while its application in place of expression is not very obvious.

Comment: @astentx The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/LNNVL.html) states "The function can be used in the `WHERE` clause of a query, or as the `WHEN` condition in a searched `CASE` expression." It is not intended to be used directly in `SELECT` clause as you did in your first fiddle.

Comment: @MT0 And after it: "LNNVL can be used anywhere a scalar expression can appear". I've mentioned this function because it may be used in the non-functional context (as a standalone condition) as well as an expression (function call). While its application as a condition is straightforward, its application as an expression is not (though, documentation includes it in the Function section, not an Condition section, and mentions its usage as a function).

Answer (score 0):

The `BOOLEAN` data type is a PL/SQL only data type and is not supported in Oracle SQL statements.

Use two constants:

- `0` for false, `1` (or non-zero) for true (as per the C language).
- `0` for no errors, non-zero for errors (as per Unix program exit codes).
- `'Y'` for yes, `'N'` for no.
- `'success'` and `'failure'`
- etc.

Whatever you return is your personal preference. Document the convention you are going to use and then use it consistently so that everyone on the same project uses the same convention.

> Unless there is another way?

No, just pick a convention for truthy/falsy values and stick to that.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WITH
    FUNCTION f_check_int ( p_str VARCHAR2 )
         RETURN VARCHAR2  ------- Y / N
IS
   lv_data NUMBER;
BEGIN
   lv_data := TO_NUMBER(p_str);
   IF lv_data>0 AND MOD(lv_data,1)=0 THEN
      RETURN 'Y';
   ELSE
      RETURN 'N';
   END IF;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN VALUE_ERROR THEN
        RETURN 'N';
END;

A AS (SELECT 1 a FROM DUAL)
SELECT *
  FROM a
 WHERE f_check_int(a.a) = 'Y'
```

Comment: Good answer but it's always good to add a sentence or two